# Do something after sending email

Tags: email, wp-mail

I want to do something after WordPress sent an email. For example, after sending "Reset Password" email using `wp_mail()` function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Using the PHPMailer class with an action callback:

I did some digging into the [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cb39d03501aae82c7f16f67c93ab0452ef870c46/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php) class and found that it supports a [custom action](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cb39d03501aae82c7f16f67c93ab0452ef870c46/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php#L393).

[Here's](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cb39d03501aae82c7f16f67c93ab0452ef870c46/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php#L3231) how the callback is activated with the [`doCallback()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cb39d03501aae82c7f16f67c93ab0452ef870c46/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php#L3231) method in the class.

There's also a `PHPMailer` [test](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/199bd9698b9b2b2c6b09e046fd12118fd10a7f73/test/test_callback.php) on GitHub using this feature via the `callbackAction()` callback.

We can set it up in WordPress with:

```
$phpmailer->action_function = 'wpse_mail_action';
```

where `wpse_mail_action()` is the action callback.

Here's an example how we can apply this:

```
/**
 * Custom PHPMailer action callback
 */
function wpse_mail_action( $is_sent, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body, $from )
{
    do_action( 'wpse_mail_action', $is_sent, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body, $from );
    return $is_sent; // don't actually need this return!
}

/**
 * Setup a custom PHPMailer action callback
 */
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function( $phpmailer )
{
    $phpmailer->action_function = 'wpse_mail_action';
} );
```

Now we have access to the `wpse_mail_action` hook.

We could then add our own mail logger and check if the mails were successfully sent or not.

### Example:

Here's an (untested) example how we could do something after "Password Reset" posts are sent:

```
/**
 * Do something after the "Password Reset" post has been successfully sent:
 */
add_action( 'wpse_mail_action', function( $is_sent, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body, $from )
{
    if( $is_sent && false !== stripos( $subject, 'Password Reset' ) )
        // do stuff

}, 10, 7 );
```

where we could add some further restrictions and wrap into other actions if neccessary, like the `retrieve_password` hook.

Comment: Thank you at all. I've just made the plugin and its now accessible from wordpress plugin directory: https://wordpress.org/plugins/telegram-for-wp

Comment: You're welcome and congratulation with the new plugin @AmirMousavi

Comment: There is a conflict with Contact Form 7 plugin. It can't receive the result of sending. Its Ajax loader has been spinning forever; even when email sent successfully.

Comment: I tested this method with the CF7 and it worked as expected. If the ajaxloader is spinning forever, it  could indicate unrelated javascript/PHP/Server errors and therefore `wp_mail()` might never be called within CF7. Note that 3rd party plugins are off topic here on WPSE. @AmirMousavi