# Wordpress sending emails continuously. How to stop it?

Tags: plugins, email

Recently I'm going to test wp_mail function. I wrote below code into a plugin file:
`wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', 'The message' );`

and I entered my email instead of me@example.net. Now WordPress continuously send email to me. I don't know how to stop it! There are over 1000 mails in just 15 minutes. Please help me. I disabled all plugins and even delete pluggable.php file.

The context is :

```
function twp_mail_action($result, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body){
    $nt = new Notifygram();
    $_apikey = get_option('twp_api_key');
    $_apitoken = get_option('twp_api_token');
    $_projectname = get_option('twp_project_name');
    $nt->Notifygram($_apikey,$_apitoken, $_projectname );
    $nt->notify($body);
    wp_mail( 'myemail@gmail.com', 'The subject', 'The message' );
}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function( $phpmailer ){
    $phpmailer->action_function = 'twp_mail_action';
    } );
```

Comment: Where is the code? Please post it in context.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I added it to question. Please help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The problem

I think the problem here is that you're generating an infinite loop, by placing `wp_mail()` inside the `$phpmailer->action_function` callback, that fires after each email.

Each time you send an email with `wp_mail()`, you call `wp_mail()` again, and again, and again ... etc

### Possible workaround

You should instead use, for example, the following approach:

```
function twp_mail_action($result, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body){

    // Here we remove the phpmailer_init action callback, to avoid infinite loop:
    remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_phpmailer_init' );

    // Send the test mail:
    wp_mail( 'myemail@gmail.com', 'The subject', 'The message' );

    // Here we add it again
    add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_phpmailer_init' );

}

add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_phpmailer_init' );

function wpse_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer )
{
    $phpmailer->action_function = 'twp_mail_action';
}
```

Note that this is **untested**, so be careful testing this only on a server where you can clear the mail queue yourself, if mistakes are made in the testing ;-)

### Better:

Log your tests to a file instead, for example.

### Limit the delivery of emails

It would be interesting if we could limit the number of sent emails, per page load, while doing tests.

Here's one idea for such a plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Limit Delivered Emails
 * Description: Set an upper limit to number of sent emails per page load.
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193455/26350
 */
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function( $phpmailer )
{
    $max_emails_per_page_load = 10; // <-- Edit this to your needs!

   if( did_action( 'phpmailer_init' ) > $max_emails_per_page_load )
       $phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();

} );
```

where we clear the *to/cc/bc* fields, with the `ClearAllRecipients()` method, to stop the email delivery.

We could also throw an uncaught error with:

```
throw new \phpmailerException( __( 'Too many emails sent!' ) );
```

instead of using:

```
$phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
```

This is related to my [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190933/26350) regarding the use of the `PHPMailer` class.

Comment: Now how can I stop it?! Deleting all wordpress files?

Comment: Just don't call `wp_mail()` inside `$phpmailer->action_function` as explained in the answer.

Comment: @cybmeta I've deleted the whole plugin files and pluggable.php and class-phpmailer.php but there is no success

Comment: @AmirMousavi I can't believe it's still running, but you can kill it with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526701/stopping-an-infinite-loop-on-a-remote-server-php

Comment: I suspect the php process is long dead but that while it was alive it filled up your e-mail server with a _very_ long queue. You could try to kill the e-mail server. If you don't know how do that, I'd recommended contacting your host. Though I suspect (hope) the e-mails would dry up before you would get a response...

Comment: @AmirMousavi you must likely got a long queue in your sendmail/postfix. You should check the status of the queue, see for example [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/58196/how-do-i-check-the-postfix-queue-size)

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks Stephen. I sent them a ticket.

Comment: @birgire I've no access to server. I'm using a shared host.

Comment: I agree with @StephenHarris. You could get a very, very long queue-- 5 figures-- in a very short time with that code. Infinite loops are nasty beasts.

Comment: @AmirMousavi I updated the answer with some ideas, like how to put an upper limit on the number of sent email per page load.

Comment: Thanks for nice and detailed answers. The host support team said that there is no process on the server to kill. They told me to set the permissons of pluggable and phpmailer to 000. But it still sends email. Over thousands email... @birgire

Comment: @AmirMousavi you're welcome and hopefully this will stop delivering to you soon. But it sounds like the support team were looking for a PHP process to kill, but the problem is most likely a very long mail queue.

Comment: @birgire good news! Finally it stopped. Very very thank you :)

Comment: @AmirMousavi great to hear that, so hopefully you can tell your grandchildren a funny story about this adventure, in the future ;-)