# Contact Form 7 - Execute code AFTER mail send

Tags: hooks, plugin-contact-form-7

I've figured out how to do something BEFORE sending the mail, but I also need an action to happen AFTER it's been send.

I tried `wpcf7_after_send_mail` but with no success...

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use the additional settings in the contact form plugin settings? - http://contactform7.com/additional-settings/

Comment: I was just reading about that as i'm Googling, but i don't where those settings are. Does this allow to redirect a certain form though? I just need 1 specific form to be redirected, not all forms.

Comment: Maybe you could apply [this kind of approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190928/do-something-after-sending-email) ?

Comment: Ahh just found it and works like a charm :D
My Wordpress is in Dutch, hence why i couldn't find the Additional Fields that easily xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Please note that as of 2017 ['on_sent_ok' is deprecated](https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/). This means that your code will stop working at some point in the future (likely by the end of 2017). The recommended solution is using DOM event listeners directly. For example, if you used:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );"
```

You should replace it with:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
}, false );
```

The JavaScript code can be placed e.g. in the footer of your page.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Ok figured it out. In the specific form settings, go to the additional fields tab. Type in the following:
`on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.website-redirect.com');"`

It's working like a charm for me now. Hope this helps other developers in the future as well.

[image]

I know the image is in Dutch ... but you can't miss it with the **big red lines** around the tab name.

Comment: how we save cookie using Additional Tab? I try this `on_submit: "ooid = document.getElementById('customer_orderid').value;document.cookie = 'myorderiiid='+ooid+'; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2025 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';";` but no cookie saved.. WHY?

Comment: Please note that this was a question from TWO YEARS ago ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough reputation to add it as a comment at that time, so the only way to include this info was through edit.

Answer (score 16):

For anybody still landing here looking for a way to run some PHP code after the email has been sent, Contact Form 7 has a `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook for exactly this. Usage looks a little like:

```
// ...in functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
});
```

There is also `wpcf7_mail_failed`, which lets you hook into when the email fails.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Which version of CF7 are you using? I have this working using version 4.6.1 with WordPress 4.7.2

Comment: I think I've found the error in my code: I've wrapped my add_action call with a has_action check. But probably when my code (inside a plugin) is executed, the wpcf7_mail_sent action doesn't exist yet.  Remove the has_action check made it work.

Comment: What is this ($cf7) parameter? do i need this

Comment: It's an instance of `WPCF7_ContactForm`, which contains a bunch of information about the form that was submitted.


For example, you could get the id of the form with `$cf7->id()`. You may not need it, in which case you can leave it off until the need arises.


Here's a link to the class in GitHub incase you wanted to flick through what it does: https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/contact-form.php

Answer (score 2):

Using on_sent_ok as explained at [contactform7.com/additional-settings](http://contactform7.com/additional-settings/) can be very useful for adding some simple JavaScript like [redirecting to another page](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/).

However it is rather prone to failing due to Javascript conflicts with either your current WordPress theme or one of the other plugins you are using.

on_sent_ok is the absolutely last thing that runs in Contact Form 7, so any interferring Javascript Conflict can stop this completing.

As an alternative, Contact Form 7 has a large number of hooks which are listed at http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/. These can provide a better targeted, more robust solution.